# How can I make my iOS TTTextEditor rounded corners less aliased in Three20?

Tags: iphone, uiview, three20, antialiasing

I am trying to reproduce the UI for the iphone/iOS SMS app in my application. I am adapting the Three20 TTTextBarController. Unfortunately, my efforts have resulted in a bar that is substantially uglier because of aliasing near the rounded corners.

[image]

(StackOverflow shrinks the above image - please view the above image in full-screen mode. At that resolution you will see the aliasing).

The Three20 style code I have used to create the text bar element is as follows:

```
- (TTStyle*)textBarTextField {
    return
    [TTShapeStyle styleWithShape:[TTRoundedRectangleShape shapeWithRadius:13] next:
     [TTInsetStyle styleWithInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, 3, 6) next:
      [TTInsetStyle styleWithInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 0, 1, 0) next:
       [TTShadowStyle styleWithColor:RGBACOLOR(255,255,255,0.4) blur:0 offset:CGSizeMake(0, 1) next:
        [TTSolidFillStyle styleWithColor:RGBACOLOR(255,255,255,1.0) next:
         [TTInnerShadowStyle styleWithColor:RGBACOLOR(0,0,0,0.4) blur:3 offset:CGSizeMake(0, 2) next:
          [TTBevelBorderStyle styleWithHighlight:RGBACOLOR(0,0,0,0.25) shadow:RGBACOLOR(0,0,0,0.2)
                                           width:1 lightSource:270 next:nil]]]]]]];
}
```

Can anyone advise how to improve the quality of the rounded corners? Alternatively, has anyone figured out how to pixel-for-pixel emulate the iOS SMS chat bar?

Thanks!

**Update**

My original code came from TTDefaultStyles.m.

After simplifying I came to this style:

```
return
[TTShapeStyle styleWithShape:[TTRoundedRectangleShape shapeWithRadius:13] next:
 [TTInsetStyle styleWithInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, 4, 6) next:
   [TTLinearGradientBorderStyle styleWithColor1:RGBCOLOR(51,51,51)
                                         color2:RGBCOLOR(102, 102, 102) width:1 next:
    [TTSolidFillStyle styleWithColor:RGBACOLOR(255,255,255,1.0) next:
     [TTInnerShadowStyle styleWithColor:RGBACOLOR(0,0,0,0.8) blur:3 offset:CGSizeMake(0, 2) next:nil
     ]]]]];
```

From what I can tell, the TTInnerShadowStyle is what is causing the aliasing to be visible on the top left and right. I'd love to get the code that Apple is using for their seamless UITextField shadow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the HPGrowingTextView and GrowingTextView sample code here: http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms

Not only does it look like the iOS messages app, but it also grows to multilines.

Comment: Indeed, I have moved to using HPGrowingTextView in my code instead of Three20's. Facebook Messenger also uses HPGrowingTextView.

Answer (score 1):

Use MFMessageComposeViewController in MessageUI.framework

Comment: So this would be nice, but unfortunately I don't actually want to send an SMS, I just want the UI code behind the vertically growing text box and send button. Doesn't look like you can split that out of that API. Also I have to support down to iOS 3.1 (I have many users on 2G devices).

Comment: ok, in that case i suggest to take a screenshot on retina display, ccut it. And accept background on uiTextfield and uibutton with: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_input_bg_png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(half_of_image_original_height) topCapHeight:(half_of_image_original_height)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];  And you don't need tree20 styleing. Or use full sendbar anti-aliasing, not just the contorls.

Answer (score 0):

I would strip down your style… you have 2 insets in a row, a drop shadow and bevel border, and all in a random order too. Any of these could be causing your blurriness. Why don't you start with just a simple `TTShapeStyle`, then the `TTInnerShadowStyle`.

Comment: I did simplify, and it turns out the TTInnerShadowStyle is what is causing the aliasing.

Comment: Great. turn down your blur on that style.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your view to not draw opaque.  The view is drawing with transparencies.